# Global variables in Angular, stored with angularLocalStorage

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to make one place where I can store all my variables that must be saved in LocalStorage/Cookie (I am using angularLocalStorage plugin).
What is the best way to do that?

Thanks very  much in advance.

Comment: create a dedicated service .....

Comment: leave them in the `angularLocalStorage` :-) - You should tell more about your use case - but I'd think a service would be the best.

Comment: When i are setting it in angularLocalStorage I am using a string as a name. I would like to get it "type safe" :-) Does it make sense?

Comment: Thanks very much for your comments, I made it as a service :-) @cétia how can I confirm your answer as the solution?

Answer (score 0):

You should create a service. This will have a few advantages :

- easily mockable if you want to unit test
- it's allways a good idea to create modular components, its's easier to maintain and good for readability.

;)